# How to use neo4j from a docker image on the Google Cloud Platform

Tags: docker, neo4j, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to run neo4j from the google cloud shell and I have already ssh'd into my project.

Currently I am using the following to run [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/):

```
docker run \
--publish=7474:7474 \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \
--volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs:/logs \
neo4j:3.0
```

The command works and prints the following output:

```
Starting Neo4j.
2017-12-13 03:22:34.661+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 3.0.12 ========
2017-12-13 03:22:34.681+0000 INFO  No SSL certificate found, 
generating a self-signed certificate..
2017-12-13 03:22:35.163+0000 INFO  Starting...
2017-12-13 03:22:35.631+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
2017-12-13 03:22:37.966+0000 INFO  Started.
2017-12-13 03:22:39.041+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at 
http://0.0.0.0:7474/
```

However, when I follow the link to `http://0.0.0.0:7474/`, it redirects to something like `https://7474-dot-3282369-dot-devshell.appspot.com/?authuser=0` and I get an error:

```
Error: Could not connect to Cloud Shell on port 7474.
```

What can I do differently or what additional info would you need? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are facing one of the two following issues:

**1. If you ssh'd in a different machine and the server is running there**

The issue is that you accessed an instance from the Google Cloud Shell, then you started the server through docker. At this point I think that you connected (not intentionally) to the Cloud Shell on the port 7474 clicking on "Web preview" of the same Window!
But the server was running on a different machine!

Therefore the Cloud Shell informed you that is not listening on port 7474. To solve this issue you need to retrieve the public/external IP of your instance, create a firewall rule allowing the TCP:7474 traffic and connect to it from any browser with http://ip-your-machine:7474.

**2. If you are running the server in the Google Cloud Shell**

First of all you should not run a server on the Google Cloud Shell, it is not a normal virtual machine and you should never rely on it.

By the way I followed step by step what you did:
I accessed the Google Cloud Shell, I have run your code, I obtained the very same output, but when I have done the "Web preview" I correctly visualised the neo4j login page.

Thus, I believe that if you were running the server here you unintentionally stopped it before checking the "Web preview".

**P.S.**

The weird domain name you have been redirected to: https://7474-dot-3282369-dot-devshell.appspot.com is a domain name that points exactly to your Google Cloud Shell #3282369 on port 7474.

You are redirected automatically clicking on a link  from the Cloud Shell, (since you [cannot reach 0.0.0.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) from your computer).

Comment: Okay this makes sense. It was actually case #2.
When I log go to log in, do you know what the host should be? I know both the default name and password are `neo4j`. I tried putting in the external ip of my vm, but it doesn't work, returning `ServiceUnavailable: WebSocket connection failure.`

Comment: I am sorry, I am not sure I understood your question, have you been able to log in? When I connect to the Web Preview on the port 7474 I have the possibility to log in and to change the password; then I can go through documentation, run the code, ecc. Where did you got that error? Where did you put the IP?

Comment: I have not been able to log in. When I go to https://7474-dot-3282369-dot-devshell.appspot.com, I get a neo4j browser with the window that shows up if you type `:server connect`.

There are three boxes: host, username, and password. I tried putting the ip as the host, and it is the host I am trying to figure out.

Comment: It is really weird because I got two boxes only: username and password.
Try to stop the server and re run the code: `docker run --publish=7474:7474 --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data2:/data --volume=$HOME/neo4j/logs2:/logs neo4j:3.0` I changed only the volume name, in this way you will start in a brand new environment.

Comment: This is the log in form I visualise http://guides.grails.org/neo4j-movies/img/neo4j-password.png

Comment: In the end have you been able to log in?

Comment: I recognize the log in form you linked to, as that is the login form I usually get when running neo4j elsewhere. However, I have not been able to log in, as I still need to figure out the host. Perhaps I will make a new question so that the answer doesn't get buried in these comments when I do get it figured out. Regardless, you have been very helpful, so thank you!